# Why won't Ubuntu install on my Shuttle?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, shuttle

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on an old Shuttle, using a USB stick. On booting, I get a screen with GNU GRUB 2.06 and a menu of 4 choices:

```
Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Test memory
```

Apart from test memory (which *does* report some errors, but I think a memory hole fixes that; anyway the BIOS also tests memory and reports no errors) any of the first 3 options simply brings up a dark screen with a cursor flashing top left. I have left it for several minutes but nothing more has happened.

Here's the background. I have downloaded both ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso ubuntu-22.10-desktop-amd64.iso on my iMac and used BalenaEtcher to flash them to USB sticks. I have tried 2 different sticks and two different USB ports in case they were at fault. The Shuttle specs are:

```
Processor: 3GHz Pentium(R) CPU with Hyper-Threading Technology
Memory: 1GB
Disk: Maxtor 6Y120L0, 120GB
Optical: Optiarc DVD RW AD-5200A 1.05
```

Not ideal, but surely adequate. The Shuttle currently runs Windows XP from the hard disk.

I could perhaps boot Ubuntu off the DVD drive instead, but I thought the USB route was simpler and more likely to succeed.

Any suggestions? Thanks ...

Comment: 1 GB of RAM is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see at the [official web site](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Minimum requirements for Ubuntu 22.04 are:

> 4 GB system memory

1 GB is obviously not enough.

Comment: Ah. I read that as "recommended system requirements" and not "mandatory system requirements." I will look for something smaller. thanks for taking the time to point out an elementary error :)

Comment: This is a bit confusing, but really Ubuntu won't work on 1 GB. It may work more or less OK on 3 GB, but not on 1.